# Casting [String:String] to my own Class in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm trying to cast or convert a dictionary in to an object but I'm not sure how to do it.

This is my class:

```
import Foundation

class DTOStore: NSObject {

    var _Id: Int64?
    var _StoreId:String?
    var _Name:String?
    var _Address:String?

    var Id: Int64 {
        get {
            return _Id!
        }
        set (pValue) {
            _Id = pValue
        }
    }

    var StoreId:String {
        get {
            return _StoreId!
        }
        set (pValue) {
            _StoreId = pValue
        }
    }

    var Name:String {
        get {
            return _Name!
        }
        set (pValue) {
            _Name = pValue
        }
    }

    var Address:String {
        get {
            return _Address!
        }
        set (pValue) {
            _Address = pValue
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
let vDTOStore:DTOStore = SQLiteConnectionManager.selectRowDatabase(vCommand, pNumColumns: 4) as! DTOStore
```

Where the result of SQLiteConnectionManager.selectRowDatabase(vCommand, pNumColumns: 4) is a [String:String] dictionary, taking in consideration that the function will be casted as lot of different objects, that is why it always return a [String:String].

But as you can guess it does not work, and I have no clue on how to do it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Apart from the problem it's absolutely unusual to use backing instance variables in Swift. And why are those instance variables optional? They will never be `nil`.

Comment: When would there ever be a store without an id, store id (which is different?), name or address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot **cast** a dictionary to a custom object.
You need to **map** it by  writing an appropriate initializer.

Your object can be reduced to

```
class DTOStore: NSObject {

    let id: Int64
    let storeId: String
    var name: String
    var address: String

    init(dictionary: [String:String]) {
        self.name = dictionary["name"] ?? ""
        self.storeId = dictionary["storeId"] ?? ""
        self.address = dictionary["address"] ?? ""
        let idString = dictionary["id"] ?? "0"
        self.id = Int64(idString) ?? 0
    }

    var dictionaryRepresentation : [String:String] {
        return ["name" : name, "storeId" : storeId, "address" : address, "id" : "\(id)"]
    }
}
```

If the keys don't exist the values are set to empty string / 0.
`id` and `storeId` are declared as constants (`let`).

---

PS: Since the source of the dictionary is a SQL database which will always return **all** requested fields in **all** records and if the fields are declared as non-NULL you can even write

```
    init(dictionary: [String:String]) {
        self.name = dictionary["name"]!
        self.storeId = dictionary["storeId"]!
        self.address = dictionary["address"]!
        self.id = Int64(dictionary["id"]!)
    }
```

Comment: And there should probably be a reciprocal method that gives you a dictionary representation of `DTOStore`.

Comment: I know it's not your call but I'd also make most of those `vars` into `lets`. :D It seems unlikely that the `storeId` or `id` will change.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements, rmaddy and Fogmeister

Answer (score 3):

I will use a `struct` (but if you prefer a `class` just replace the *struct* word with *class*).

```
struct DTOStore {
    let id: Int64
    let storeId:String
    let name:String
    let address:String

    init?(dict: [String:String]) {
        guard
            let idString = dict["id"],
            let id = Int64(idString),
            let storeId = dict["storeId"],
            let name = dict["name"],
            let address = dict["address"]
            else { return nil }


        self.id = id
        self.storeId = storeId
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
    }
}
```

### Failable initializer

The `DTOStore` has a failable initializer.

This is useful when you want initialize an instance of your custom type using a dictionary or a JSON (because there's no guarantee all the required key/values will be there).

If the Failable initializer receives as input a dictionary that does not contains all the expected values, then the instance **not** created and the initializer returns `nil`.

> More info about this approach here https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: This code is failing to deal with the fact that the `id` property is of type `Int64` but the dictionary contains only strings.

Comment: @rmaddy Oops, let me fix it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your answers I have ended up doing this:

```
import Foundation

class DTOStore: NSObject {

    var _Id = Int64()
    var _StoreId = Int64()
    var _Name:String = ""
    var _Address:String = ""
    var _DTOStoreArray = [DTOStore]()

    var Id: Int64 {
        get {
            return _Id
        }
        set (pValue) {
            _Id = pValue
        }
    }

    var StoreId:Int64 {
        get {
            return _StoreId
        }
        set (pValue) {
            _StoreId = pValue
        }
    }

    var Name:String {
        get {
            return _Name
        }
        set (pValue) {
            _Name = pValue
        }
    }

    var Address:String {
        get {
            return _Address
        }
        set (pValue) {
            _Address = pValue
        }
    }

    var DTStoreArrar: [DTOStore] {
        get {
            return _DTOStoreArray
        }
    }

    init(pValue: [String:String]) {
        super.init()
        self._Id = Int64(pValue["Id"]!)!
        self._StoreId = Int64(pValue["StoreId"]!)!
        self._Name = String(pValue["Name"]!)!
        self._Address = String(pValue["Address"]!)!
    }

    init(pArray: [[String:String]]) {
        super.init()
        for vValue in pArray {
            self._DTOStoreArray.append(DTOStore(pValue: vValue))
        }
    }
}
```

And the call is like this:

```
let vDTOStore = DTOStore(pValue: SQLiteConnectionManager.selectRowDatabase(vCommand, pNumColumns: 4))
```

Happy coding.