# What to do in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a problem when it comes to taking json from a server an example of the json looks like this:

```
[{
"subject": "First Post",
"body": "This is a test post coming from mySQL server",
"user": "user",
"date": "2017-04-30",
"comments": "[]",
"id": 1 }]
```

I don't know what kind of object this would make and quite frankly how to desteralize it, if you could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that is a dictionary inside an array in swift terms. https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: A combination of @luk2302s comment and my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700443/how-to-write-own-model-mapper-in-swift-language/43700629#43700629) you will solve this.

Comment: Convert JSON Into Dicotionary  ,,,, here is your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Most important: **Read the JSON**. It's pretty easy:

- `{}` is a dictionary (`[String:Any]`).
- `[]` is an array (`[[String:Any]]` sometimes `[Any]`).
- All keys are required to be `String`.
- All values in double quotes are `String`.
- Numeric values with decimal places are `Double`.
- Numeric values without decimal places are `Int`.
- `true` /  `false` (not in double quotes) is `Bool`.
- `null` is `NSNull`.

That's the entire type set of JSON.

---

Use the [`(NS)JSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization) class to make an object from the data.
There are hundreds (I guess thousands) of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D%20parse%20JSON) here on SO.